# MySQL Master Slave Replication between AWS and GCP

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-rds, google-cloud-sql

I have been working on a project in Mysql Master slave replication. I want to setup a master slave replication between AWS and GCP where AWS has the AWS RDS as the master and the slave or replica is in the GCP side. But I want to create this replica on GCP side without publicly exposing the master instance on AWS. That means this should happen in a private network.

I have found solutions where we can create proxy for the master instance and then create replica on the GCP side using the Cloud SQL migration services. But this is not what what I want. I don't want to assign a proxy to the master instance.

The replica creation process should be within a private network.

What should I do next? Help.

Also, please do let me know if the question is still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If private network on the master (AWS) is a must, then this won't be possible. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external#server-requirements) about using Cloud SQL as External replica is clear on the requirements for the source:

> Ensure that the source database server meets these configuration requirements:
>
> - An externally accessible IPv4 address and TCP port.

Comment: Ya.. I saw this requirement. That is why I posted the question to know if there is any other way.

Comment: Won't the database Migration Service (DMS) work for this situation ?

Comment: Oh got it. It won't be possible as per the docs. I guess you are referring to this one[1] (only approach I see by now). I do understand the point on the other answer (AWS VPC -> Transit Gateway -> GCP VPC) *but* Cloud SQL has its own VPC (inside the GCP project) therefore I don't see how it would overpass that, here is another statement about the traffic being sent over public network [2]

[1] https://medium.com/@eddi.alim/mysql-aws-rds-replication-to-google-cloud-sql-f3022e9ff4
[2] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/external-server#ssltls_configuration

Comment: I went through this article. This is the only solution I found but it exposes our Master database to public. So, I was looking for a alternative to this.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Transit Gateway between AWS VPC and GCP private network.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/what-is-transit-gateway.html

Comment: How is that going to help ? Can you please give me a little more insight on this...

Comment: Transit Gateway will solve the network connection between AWS RDS MySQL to GCP MySQL without any proxy. Then you can setup replication between both using this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.MySQL.html

Comment: I have done this from VPC A from account A to another VPC B from Account B which is working with 5 seconds latency. I have used DMS which is really tough to manage tasks and maintain CDC without error, so I switched my approach to replication which is easy and will get good latency compared to DMS.